# PHP 5.4 vs 5.3 app errors

Tags: php, syntax-error

I am building an web app with php and built it in php 5.4.  However, I just realized my server run only 5.3 or 5.2.  In my controller file  I have this line of code

```
        $this->load->model('admin/upholstery_category_admin');
    $this->load->helper('url');

    if($method == 'add')
    {
        $categories = $this->db->get('category')->result();
line 158 here>>     $data = [];
        $data['cats'] = $categories;
        $data['message'] = '';
```

which is causes this error

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/content/51/6663351/html/application/controllers/admin.php on line 158
```

How do i change the syntax to correct this?

Comment: @Xeoncross - Nope. That's actually valid PHP 5.4

Answer (score 4):

change:

```
$data = [];
```

to

```
$data =array();
```

**As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with [].** So its only with 5.4 and later

Answer (score 1):

`[]` is shortened syntax for arrays. So it should be:

```
$data = array();
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP only added array literals in 5.4. Use this for PHP < 5.4:

```
$data = array();
```